# Xcode command line tools uninstall not working

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode, development

I am trying to uninstall Xcode command line tools and I used the command:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

to delete the folder but when I use the command:

```
xcode-select -p
```

it still shows the folder:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Am I doing something wrong since the folder is still showing up?

Note that when I issue the command

```
ls -al /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

the computer tells me there is indeed no such file or directory. I have confirmed that the trash is empty after deleting the folder and restarted my computer.

The computer is an M1 MacBook Air with macOS Monterey 12.2.1. Xcode was installed on it previously but I deleted the files associated with it.

Comment: I have a m1 Macbook air and I have MacOS monterey and it is version 12.2.1. I did have Xcode installed but I believe that I have deleted the files associated with it.

Comment: `xcode-select -p` prints the currently selected path.  Doesn't mean there's anything THERE.

Comment: Since it prints the current path, does that mean those folders are still there? I have tried to find them but I am not able to.

Comment: It tells me there is no such file or directory.

Comment: Then you've answered your own question.  The system was configured to use a particular path for the tools, you reached out of band to delete that directory, why would the system not still reflect what it had been told?

Comment: The guide I was following to uninstall said that the command xcode-select -p would  result in an error and not being able to get the active developer directory, is there a reason it does not show that?

Comment: I have confirmed that the trash is empty and I have restarted my computer, but it is still not showing an error.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo xcode-select --reset`?

Comment: That command seems to have done the trick, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like somehow the Xcode related settings has not been kept up-to-date along with the changes you have made on your computer. The following command to be issued through Terminal may help:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Here is the description of the `--reset` option for `xcode-select` according to the man pages:

> ```
> -r, --reset
>    Unsets any user-specified developer directory, so that the
>    developer directory will be found via the default search
>    mechanism. This command must be run with superuser permissions
>    (see sudo(8)), and will affect all users on the system.
> ```